# Nginxでレスポンスコード403を返したいのですが…

Tags: nginx

**403は返るのですが、仕組みがよく分かりません**

---

**試したこと**

confファイル

```
error_page 403 /hoge.php;
```

hoge.php

```
<?php
http_response_code(403);
```

ブラウザ画面

> 403 Forbidden nginx/1.12.2

---

**Q1.「403 Forbidden nginx/1.12.2」はどこで設定しているでしょうか？**
・どこかの画面を呼び出している？
・あるいはテキストを動的に表示しているだけ？？
・この画面で「nginx」と「バージョン」を非表示することは出来るでしょうか？
※nginx.confを確認しましたが、403については何も記述されていません

**Q2.「403 Forbidden nginx/1.12.2」はどこで設定しているのでしょうか？**
・この画面を直接呼び出すにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
・現状だと、「意図的に403設定したページ」→「error_page 403 で指定したカスタムページ」 →　「403 Forbidden nginx/1.12.2」という流れになっているのですが、カスタムページ経由ではなく、「403設定したページ」から直接この「403 Forbidden」画面を呼び出すにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

---

**質問背景**
・「403 Forbidden」にこだわりはないので、server毎に指定せず、なるべく簡単に設定したい
・Nginx自体に「403 Forbidden」表示する機能があるのならそれを利用したい

Answer (score 1):

「403エラーが発生すると、どんな事が起きるのか」
１）error_page 403 /hoge.php;　（403のエラーが発生したら、/hoge.phpを表示しなさいという意味）のconfの設定によって、hoge.phpが実行される。
２）hoge.phpでは、http_response_code(403);　で、403のHTTPレスポンス("403 Forbidden nginx/1.12.2")が表示される。
　なぜ表示されるのかというと、http_response_codeという関数が、そのように作られているから。

＝＝
「この画面で「nginx」と「バージョン」を非表示することは出来るでしょうか？」
どんな表示にするかはhoge.phpで決まります。"403 Forbidden"だけを表示したいなら、hoge.phpを以下のようにすれば良い。

```
{php?
   echo('403 Forbidden')
```